# Insisting on a job description before directly applying to company

Tags: job-search, job-description

This is very similar to the question below, except that I'm curious if people feel that it makes a difference if it's coming directly from a company instead of a recruiting firm.

[Insisting on a job description before submission to company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64415/insisting-on-a-job-description-before-submission-to-company)

Essentially, the setup is the same: a company's internal recruiter will send an email saying they came across my profile and think I might be a good fit for one of their jobs; would I be willing to talk to a recruiter?

I always think it's best to have a job description, for the same reasons as the other question, even for the actual company. But is insisting on a job description when it's the actual company just being a stickler for rules?

Answer (score 2):

> a company's internal recruiter will send an email saying they came
>   across my profile and think I might be a good fit for one of their
>   jobs; would I be willing to talk to a recruiter?

When people drop off their resume at a job fair, and then are asked to talk to a recruiter they generally have started the process without knowing exactly which jobs they would be perfect for.

The internal recruiter could be trying to gauge your interest in one of several positions. They may vary is experience level, focus, or location. They may also need to determine at an early stage if you can meet a requirement that generally isn't included on a resume. This requirement may be so important that not being able to meet it makes you undesirable in the eyes of the company.

The difference between the internal and external requiter is that the external recruiter is trying to fill their resume bank to be used to submit to multiple companies, while an internal recruiter is trying to fill the resume bank used to hire people to their company.

If you have any interest in the company you should at least talk to the recruiter. You can ask them questions. It you don't feel that they have possible positions for you, then you can end it there.

Comment: I think your third paragraph gets to the crux of the matter. External recruiters may be likely to play games or downright abuse candidates in order to make placements with the goal of collecting their commission. Internal recruiters are much less likely to play games, and don't need to trick people or spam a huge number of positions/resumes.

Comment: A job fair is a little different scenario in that the company and the applicant have not communicated before. In my example, it's the company that initiates contact: "I came across your profile...". Also in a job fair, you usually have a few minutes to discuss the company and their range of jobs with the recruiters they send to collect resumes.

Answer (score 1):

Some recruiters are better than others. However, think practically: is the recruiter going to put you in contact with the company at the time of your choice? Definitely no.

So you will get the job description from the recruiter anyway. You cannot know if the recruiter altered it or not.

So, the answer to the other question is your best option: be happy if you at least have a job description.

---

There are many examples on the net, but I have one of my own.

A recruiter on LinkedIn (claiming that she had awards for best recruiter and other merits) asked me to update my CV in order to include experience I did not have. I stated firmly that the CV will keep its contents, but she can update it as she wishes - protecting myself for lying. She had the guts to insist that she cannot modify the CV, and that I have to state false information, from some benefit she might have had.

So, if the info goes strictly through the recruiter, you cannot know what you get anyway.

---

What you can do is that when you finally get in contact with the company, you ask them if the job description that was given to you is the real job description, or it was altered.

Comment: This question is explicitly asking about working directly with an employer's internal recruiter, while your answer seems to be about working with an independent, external, third party recruiter. Unless I'm missing something it doesn't look like you're addressing the actual question.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to answer. This response answers the question I linked about external recruiters. My question is about internal recruiters.

Answer (score 1):

Depending a little bit on the company (size, business) I don't think it is very weird that there is no job description. It could very well be that there is an opening but no proper profile or exact description yet when someone stumbled on your profile. It could be that they are looking for an addition to a team with a skill set in either this or that direction (a research team for instance).

That ofcourse does mean that they should atleast be able to tell you roughly what they are looking for, either on the phone or by email. You will be investing time (by going to meet them) so it is not weird to ask.

So yes I think there is a difference when it comes from the company directly. They could be still in the early stages of looking for someone new and it is more reasonable and believable that they do not have a proper job description yet.